# Querying datastore entity with NodeJS client API by safe-Url

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-datastore, datastore, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm trying to query datastore entity with NodeJS client API (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/datastore) given safe-url string provided by existing Go code. For some reason while other APIs (Go, Python,...) enable to decode/encode from/to safe-Url to key, NodeJS doesn't. Is there other way to do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Feature Request, created by OP, in the [official repository](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-datastore/issues/152) for the library. At this moment, it has no ETA.